# Node node-csv-parse gives "has no method 'join'" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, csv

Can't seem to get the pipe function working properly as I am getting a "TypeError: Object # has no method 'join'" error. My input file is a very basic comma delimitated csv, nothing too fancy.

I'd like to pipe the output directly to my response.

```
var output = [];
var parser = parse({auto_parse: true, columns: true});
var input = fs.createReadStream('./uploads/' + req.body.file);
var transformer = transform(function (record, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(null, record.join(' ') + '\n');
    }, 500);
}, {parallel: 10});

transformer.on('error', function (err) {
    res.send(500,err);
    console.log(output);
});
transformer.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('finish');
    console.log(output);
});

input.pipe(parser).pipe(transformer).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: why do you need stream processing for the simple csv, can't you read it all into a string and split() it up?

Comment: Are you using the stream-transform node module? The clear answer is record is not an Array. My test using the stream-transform module, shows 'record' is an Object